# How to save a matlab source code into a string in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I want to save a matlab source code into a string format in matlab. Does anyone know how to do this? For example,

```
type xxx.m
```

can display the source code of xxx.m. Then using what command am I able to save it into a string?

Comment: I want to store the source file in a string format variable in matlab.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two approaches to this that I can think of are:

1. Storing the output of `type filename` into a string using `evalc`, for example:

   ```
   str = evalc('type filename');
   ```
2. Directly reading the file and storing its contents into a string, for instance:

   ```
   C = textread(filename, '%s', 'delimiter', '');
   str = sprintf('%s\n', C{:});
   ```

   There are, of course, alternative ways of doing this with `textscan`, `fgets`, `fgetl`, etc...

The resulting `str` should now hold the contents of your file.

Answer (score 0):

```
fid=fopen('filename.whatever','r')
txt=fread(fid,'uint8=>char')' %note the transpose!
```